# password protected iOS custom settings bundle

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, settings, appsettings

I want to create a password protected iOS custom settings bundle. So, when user needs to change a settings he will be prompted to enter a password. But using the normal settings bundle this is not possible. How can I make such a custom settings bundle?

If it is not possible how can I make a password protected custom settings screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't invoke the passcode screen of the general settings, but you can implement your own passcode screen with components like that :

[Passcode open-source components](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=passcode)

So you can add in your app settings a UISwich to enable the feature, and prompt the passcode screen to add a new code, and when you have a protected section, tell the passcode with the component.